# Set opacity with javascript in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, opacity

How can I get this "opacity-fallback" to work in IE 8?

I only want to use pure Javascript, no CSS or jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/snabbdesign/LeLfB/11/

Comment: I know that it will not have any nice fading effect bellow IE10...

Comment: You are using CSS, you are just setting it with JavaScript. ;) Also e normally is used to mean event, not element.

Comment: If you want a fading effect in browsers that don't have CSS transitions (like any version of IE) and don't want to use any library that already has this built in, then you will have to do your own javascript animation.  This involves calculating a step value, setting a timer and stepping the opacity value in small increments over time.  A good algorithm keeps track of whether it is ahead or behind schedule vs. the plan and adjusts the step value accordingly.  Search Google for "javascript tweening animation" for more info.  All the major libraries (YUI, jQuery, etc...) have this built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 e.filter = "alpha(opacity:" + value * 100 + ")";
```

needs to be

```
e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*100 + ')';
```

notice `style` and the `=`

Comment: `e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=20)'; ` should work to keep it simple. If you use this successfully and it doesn't show then make sure the element has height, if it doesn't set `overflow: auto;` and then the container will wrap down to the bottom of it's content and the opacity will "show up" so-to-speak.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple filters?  Like another one for an ie8 gradient?