# Opacity IE 8 Fallback with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, opacity

I have gone through this post:

[Set opacity with javascript in IE 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845287/set-opacity-with-javascript-in-ie-8)

This was purely done with javascript, i am using jQuery so i want to set opacity in IE8 but i am not getting succeed using jQuery.

so far i am doing like this:

```
$('.set').click(function (e) {
         var hiddenSection = $('div.hidden');
         hiddenSection.fadeIn()
         .css({ 'display': 'block' })
         .css({ width: $(window).width() + 'px', height: $(window).height() + 'px' })
         .css({ top: ($(window).height() - hiddenSection.height()) / 2 + 'px',
         left: ($(window).width() - hiddenSection.width()) / 2 + 'px'})
         .css({ 'background-color': 'rgb(190,190,190)'}) //Here bgcolor
         .css({ 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=1000)' }) // here opacity 
         .appendTo('body');
         $('span.close').click(function () { $(hiddenSection).fadeOut(); });
});
```

Is there anyway to achieve this CSS opacity in IE 8, the i know IE8 doesn't support opacity, but the post that i mentioned gets this done in IE 8 also.

This sentence `.css({ 'filter': 'alpha(opacity=**val**)' })` might have something to break.

How can i get this working in IE 8?

**Note:**

Please avoid `rgba()` i know its also doesn't work with IE 8

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that jQuery has code that normalises jquery code like `.css('opacity')` so that it works in old IE versions without you needing to mess around with filters. Also, if you want to use rgba, you can use it in old IE with the help of Css3Pie.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

So in your case:

```
.css({ '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=**val**)' })
```

The filter opacity value can be an integer between 0 and 100.

Read more [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/).

Comment: @Dhaval Did I solve your question, or do you need further help?

Comment: This did not work for me in IE8 using jQuery's css() function.